# Destination Goal not taking funnel into consideration

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

I have a very basic site goal:

When someone gets to the '/my-account' page directly from the '/component/community/ajaxregister/ajaxregister' page, it needs to count it as a conversion (Registration).

I have a custom destination goal set up:

Destination = '/my-account'
Funnel: ON
Step 1 '/component/community/ajaxregister/ajaxregister' Requires? YES

The registration counts in my db do not match the goal count and the 'Reverse Goal Path' report shows that there are conversions being registered where the 'Goal Previous - Step 1' includes pages other than the registration page.

Any ideas on how to make this goal register only when one lands on my-account from the registration page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "required step" merely affects funnel visualization, not goal conversion. So by default there is no way not make this count only when people come from the registration page.

To solve this in code (and thus make the question on topic :-) ) you could

- check the referring page on your goal conversion page, then
- fire an event when the referrer is the registration pages, and
- then switch to an event-based goal in the GA backend

That way you would not have a funnel (does not work with event based goals), but at least you'd have the "correct" number of conversions.

Comment: Thank you!  I did not realize this about the required step.